# Restore hsqldb database from .backup file

Tags: java, database, hsqldb, restore

Can someone tell me how to restore hsqldb database from .backup or .data file

All I’ve is .backup, .data, .properties and .script files.
I've encrypted PDFs in the database and I need to retrieve those and save it without encryption. I believe the database has all the file informations.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Version conflict. The back up file was in 1.8.0
Was able to restore in 2.0

https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73674/thread/62dab508f3/